# How to hide saved keyword lists from SearchView?

Tags: android, search, keyword, searchview

As you can see below, whenever I am about to enter something to SearchView, it displays a suggested list of keywords. Actually these are the saved keywords I entered long time ago.
On Nexus 4, I see this list. But on Samsung Galaxy series, the list doesn't show up.
How can I make sure that the list doesn't show up? 
I read the doc here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

but couldn't find a method like setSuggestionEnabled() or so..
Any suggestions? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hey, did u found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`, the Android documentation describes how to do it, it is pretty fast to setup:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html

They also describe how to add the possibility to clear the history.

**EDIT:**

From the documentation:

> Prevent the suggestion from being copied into a shortcut at all.
>   Provide a value of SUGGEST_NEVER_MAKE_SHORTCUT in the SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID column. In this case, the suggestion is never copied into a shortcut. This should only be necessary if you absolutely do not want the previously copied suggestion to appear. (Recall that if you provide a normal value for the column, then the suggestion shortcut appears only until the refresh query returns.)

From here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#ManagingShortcuts

Comment: yea I want to disable it ;) I dunno why the list only appears on Nexus 4. HAven't tried other nexus series yet.